# Iphone didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method

Tags: iphone

Actually, i m new for objective C.

I call webservice using NSURL. But that url consist XML argument.

example:

http://166:8081/application/service/ipad/saveGrowthRemark?remarksXML=

```
 <empId>313009</empId>     
 <criteria>PT</criteria>     
 <type>Tamp;M</type>     
 <remarks>Enter Rmarks</remarks>     
 <cluster>ALL</cluster>
```

This is the code I used to retreibe the XML

```
-(void)createConnection{    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:_urlStr];
    [request setURL:url];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

But this url does not called. Its return "bad URL" error.
what is the problem in this url.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates there’s a problem with your URL. To me, the host part `166` doesn’t look valid.